# JS calculation on standby

Tags: javascript, multitasking, chess

I've written a chess engine in JS, but it's only 'thinking' when it's it's move. Is there a way to make it calculate while I think on my own move? Like script has to calculate the best move and wait for my action simultaneously? I'd call it multitasking.

Comment: How can your script consider the best response to your move before you make it?

Comment: CalculateChessMoveOnOpponentsTurn() is in ES8 I think.

Comment: It should calculate as many possible moves as possible and when I chose one - cut the rest of the 'tree' and have some calculations done. It would definetely strenghten it's power and also shorten the time that user waits for computer to move. Most of contemporary chess engines do so. _PS. I want it to work in IE 6 too, and this function is incompatible..._

Comment: P.S. You are doing yourself a disservice by supporting IE6 - http://www.modern.ie/ie6countdown

Answer (score 1):

You could try using `setInterval()` that does a small amount of work each interval.

```
function doSomeCalculating() {
    if (nextMoveCalculated) {
        return;
    }

    var start = new Date();
    while (true) {
        // break the loop if more than 100ms have elapsed
        var now = new Date();
        if (now.getTime() - start.getTime() > 100) {
            break;
        }

        // do a small amount of calculating here (keyword small)
    }
}

setInterval(doSomeCalculating, 1000); // runs every second
```

The trick is to do a ***small*** amount of processing each callback, otherwise the UI will block.  If you notice the callback runs every 1000ms and does 100ms worth of work.

Your mileage may vary in terms of setting the intervals, but the idea is to leave plenty of CPU cycles for other browser activities.

Comment: Actually calculation with the depth of 3 lasts a few seconds (and it definetely doesn't work the way you think), but maybe it's worth to give it a try. Nevertheless I'm looking for something else.

Comment: The problem with JavaScript is that it tends to block if you have a really heavy function call (i.e. one that runs for 3 seconds).  If it is possible to break up your calculation into steps, it will result in a better UI experience.

Comment: @adam on the browser, the only way to achieve that is to use setInterval. You'll have to do some calculation and leave the function then when you'll return with the next interval, you'll have to continue the work.

Comment: @dana It's going to block because Javascript only runs in one thread. The only way to achieve this is to use setInterval and some kind of state machine that tracks changes. Each interval should be able to return after some time and continue where it was when the next interval will start. With modern javascript. Someone could use `yield` to create a generator.

Comment: @LoïcFaure-Lacroix - We are in agreement.  I guess I should have been more explicit about how long the `doSomeCalculating()` function should run.  Updating answer.  Also, note the OP wants this to work with IE6, so `yield` might not be an option.

Comment: @dana yes that's why I said for modern javascript. Also the `setInterval` could be much smaller if the time in `doSomeCalculation` is small enough. The time marked in `setInterval` is just a promise that the event will not get triggered before that time. The most complicated part is split the process in multiple parts.